# When to use "which" and "in which"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am confused with the following two sentences. Which one is correctly written?

1. the manner **in which** a person behaves
2. the manner **which** a person behaves

Comment: @KateBunting
 what I got from your comment, is... I mean is the first sentence correct ?
because "the manners IN WHICH a person behaves" looks fine to me but the second sentence seems to lack something

Comment: The second sentence certainly lacks something - correctness.

Comment: ...so the first sentence is correct and the second doesn't make sense.  I thought I had made that clear.

Comment: to behave **in** a manner is surely given in examples in dictionaries under manner.

Answer (score 4):

*Manner* is not the object of the verb *behave.* You don't behave a manner, you behave **in** a certain manner.

Comment: Thank you so much.